# How to check if process is suspended?

Tags: process, delphi-7

Following code does not compile because my Delphi 7 complains about undeclared identifier **PSYSTEM_THREAD = ^SYSTEM_THREAD**. What UNIT am I missing from USES clause? ......................................................................................................................................................

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
 Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
 Dialogs, StdCtrls;




type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Button1: TButton;

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type
  PSYSTEM_THREAD = ^SYSTEM_THREAD


var
  Form1: TForm1;

function NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemInformationClass:DWORD; SystemInformation:pointer; SystemInformationLength:DWORD; ReturnLength:PDWORD):cardinal; stdcall; external 'ntdll';

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function IsThreadSuspended:Boolean;
var spi:PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION;
    crt:PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION;
    PThreadInfo:PSYSTEM_THREAD;
    Size:DWORD;
   j:Integer;
   LastProcess:Boolean;
begin
  Result:=False; // Default result, will be also returned if any error arises.
  // If process ID is 0 then we use current process ID
  If AProcessID=0 then AProcessID:=GetCurrentProcessId;

  if (NtQuerySystemInformation(5,nil,0,@Size)=STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH) and (Size>0) then
  begin
    GetMem(spi,Size);
    try
      if NtQuerySystemInformation(5,spi,Size,@Size)=0 then
      begin

        crt:=spi;
        LastProcess:=False;
        While not LastProcess do
        begin
          LastProcess:=crt^.NextEntryOffset = 0;
          if crt^.ProcessID=AProcessID then
          begin

            for j := 0 to crt^.NumberOfThreads-1 do
            begin
              PThreadInfo:=PSYSTEM_THREAD(@crt^.ThreadInfo[j]);
              if PThreadInfo^.UniqueThread = AThreadID then
              begin
                if PThreadInfo^.WaitReason = 5 then Exit(True) // the thread is suspended
                else Exit(False); // the thread is not suspended
                Break;
              end;
            end;

            Break;
          end;
          crt := Pointer(DWORD(crt) + crt^.NextEntryOffset);
        end;

       end else Exit; // failed listing processes!
     finally
        FreeMem(spi);
   end;
 end 
else Exit; // failed listing processes!
end;

end.
```

Comment: Have you tried looking [here](https://vtopan.wordpress.com/programming/undocumentedpoorly-documented-structures-in-delphi/)?  This is the first hit googling "delphi system_thread".

Answer (score -2):

Declaration

```
type
  PSYSTEM_THREADS = ^SYSTEM_THREADS;
  SYSTEM_THREADS  = packed record
  KernelTime: LARGE_INTEGER;
  UserTime: LARGE_INTEGER;
  CreateTime: LARGE_INTEGER;
  WaitTime: ULONG;
  StartAddress: Pointer;
  UniqueProcess: DWORD;
  UniqueThread: DWORD;
  Priority: Integer;
  BasePriority: Integer;
  ContextSwitchCount: ULONG;
  State: Longint;
  WaitReason: Longint;
end;

type
  PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION = ^SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION;
  SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION = packed record
    NextOffset: ULONG;
    ThreadCount: ULONG;
    Reserved1: array [0..5] of ULONG;
    CreateTime: FILETIME;
    UserTime: FILETIME;
    KernelTime: FILETIME;
    ModuleNameLength: WORD;
    ModuleNameMaxLength: WORD;
    ModuleName: PWideChar;
    BasePriority: ULONG;
    ProcessID: ULONG;
    InheritedFromUniqueProcessID: ULONG;
    HandleCount: ULONG;
    Reserved2 : array[0..1] of ULONG;
    PeakVirtualSize : ULONG;
    VirtualSize : ULONG;
    PageFaultCount : ULONG;
    PeakWorkingSetSize : ULONG;
    WorkingSetSize : ULONG;
    QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage : ULONG;
    QuotaPagedPoolUsage : ULONG;
    QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage : ULONG;
    QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage : ULONG;
    PageFileUsage : ULONG;
    PeakPageFileUsage : ULONG;
    PrivatePageCount : ULONG;
    ReadOperationCount : LARGE_INTEGER;
    WriteOperationCount : LARGE_INTEGER;
    OtherOperationCount : LARGE_INTEGER;
    ReadTransferCount : LARGE_INTEGER;
    WriteTransferCount : LARGE_INTEGER;
    OtherTransferCount : LARGE_INTEGER;
    ThreadInfo: array [0..0] of SYSTEM_THREADS;
end;

function NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemInformationClass:DWORD; SystemInformation:pointer; SystemInformationLength:DWORD; ReturnLength:PDWORD):cardinal; stdcall; external 'ntdll';
```

Function

```
function IsProcessSuspended(PID:Cardinal):Boolean;
var spi:PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION;
    crt:PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION;
    PThreadInfo:PSYSTEM_THREADS;
    Size:DWORD;
    LastProcess:Boolean;
const
   STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = $C0000004;
begin
  Result:=False;
  if (NtQuerySystemInformation(5,nil,0,@Size)=STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH) and (Size>0) then
  begin
    GetMem(spi,Size);
    try
      if NtQuerySystemInformation(5,spi,Size,@Size)=0 then
      begin
        crt:=spi;
        LastProcess:=False;
        While LastProcess=false do
        begin
          LastProcess:=crt^.NextOffset=0;
          if crt^.ProcessID=PID then
          begin
            PThreadInfo:=PSYSTEM_THREADS(@crt^.ThreadInfo[0]);  //check only main thread
            if PThreadInfo^.WaitReason=5 then Result:=True else Result:=False;
            Break;
          end;
          crt:=Pointer(DWORD(crt)+crt^.NextOffset);
        end;
      end
      else Exit; // failed listing processes!
    finally
      FreeMem(spi);
    end;
  end
  else Exit; // failed listing processes!
end;
```

Comment: This is not an answer. It's simply a code dump that offers no explanation of what the code does or how it solves the OP's problem.